# Having issue with Symfony 3 Unit testing that has session enabled

Tags: php, unit-testing, session, console-application, symfony-3.4

I am new in unit testing. I have Symfony 3 console command application which is using symfony session for temporary data store.

In my unit test class I extend KernelTestCase which give me error while I tested it but if I extend `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TestSessionListener` class then the error gone and passed the test.

After some time I realize that it always passed test no mater what I write inside the test case.

#### My Console class

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // Retrieve the argument value using getArgument()
        $csv_name = $input->getArgument('file');

        // Check file name
        if ($csv_name == 'input.csv') {
            // Get input file from filesystem
            $csvData = array_map('str_getcsv', file($this->base_path.'/../web/'.$csv_name));
            $formatData = Helpers::formatInputData($csvData);

            // Start session
            $session = new Session();
            $session->start();

            foreach ($csvData as $key => $data) {
                if (!empty($data[0])) {
                    $validation = Validator::getInformationData($data, $formatData[$data[1]]);
                    if (!empty($validation)) {
                        $output->writeln($validation);
                    } else {
                        $output->writeln('valid');
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $output->writeln('Invalid file!');
        }
    }
```

#### My test case

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TestSessionListener as BaseTestSessionListener;

class DocumentCommandTest extends BaseTestSessionListener
{
    /**
     * Test Execute
     *
     */
    public function testExecute()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->add(new DocumentCommand($kernel->getContainer()));

        $command = $application->find('identification-requests:process');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(array(
            'command' => $command->getName(),
            'file' => 'input.csv'
        ));

        $output = $commandTester->getOutput();
        $this->assertContains('valid',$output);
    }
}
```

After that I also tried to extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\SessionTest`

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\SessionTest;

class DocumentCommandTest extends SessionTest
{
```

but it give me the following error

```
E.........                                                        10 / 10 (100%)

Time: 4.72 seconds, Memory: 20.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\AppBundle\Command\DocumentCommandTest::testExecute
InvalidArgumentException: The option "test_case" must be set.
```

My expected output from console is the following that needs to be tested

```
$ php bin/console identification-requests:process input.csv
valid
valid
valid
document_number_length_invalid
request_limit_exceeded
valid
document_is_expired
valid
document_type_is_invalid
valid
valid
document_number_invalid
valid
document_issue_date_invalid
```

Comment: Why do you need $session ($session = new Session();)?

Comment: I have to store data in temporarily for further process and didn't find any other easiest way to do that

Comment: what data do you need to store? I don't see in code

Comment: It is some string not longer than five character. This is my code that is using session 
`$session = new Session();
      $getCD = $session->get($countryCode);
      $getCD = 1+$getCD;
      $session->set($countryCode, $getCD);`

Comment: I don't understand why? Please post all code

Comment: Since it is longer, please follow the following link for full code.
`https://github.com/devawal/document-evaluation/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Component/Validator.php`

Comment: why don't try to use https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html istead of session for this case?

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: I update it by using cache and extends to `KernelTestCase` `class DocumentCommandTest extends KernelTestCase` and it return the following error `PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #2 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertContains() must be a array, traversable or string`

Comment: I also push it to the following repo, you can check this `https://github.com/devawal/document-evaluation/blob/master/tests/AppBundle/Command/DocumentCommandTest.php`

Comment: Using sessions inside CLI commands? Does it make any sense?

Comment: I am new in CLI command testing, I think I understand that it is not logical to use session inside CLI commands. Thanks @Andrea for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing

```
$output = $commandTester->getOutput();
$this->assertContains('valid',$output);
```

and add:

```
        $expected = 'valid
valid
valid
document_number_length_invalid
request_limit_exceeded
valid
document_is_expired
valid
document_type_is_invalid
valid
valid
document_number_invalid
valid
document_issue_date_invalid
';
        $testresult = $commandTester->getDisplay();

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $testresult);
```

see: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/c7jb/testing-symfony-console-command-with-phpunit

Comment: Although it passed the test as the output contains `valid` string, but I need to test full expected output as followed `valid
valid
valid
document_number_length_invalid
request_limit_exceeded
valid
document_is_expired
valid
document_type_is_invalid
valid
valid
document_number_invalid
valid
document_issue_date_invalid`

How can I do that? when I insert full expected string in `assertContains` then it not passed the test

Comment: I got failure. `FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.`

Comment: @AbdulAwal in example there is only one test, are you try to assert something else? Another test? are you leave `$this->assertContains('valid',$output);` ? i've tried with your code in https://github.com/devawal/document-evaluation

Comment: @AbdulAwal you forgot last character "chr(13)" for $expected variable. try copy/paste from `$expected = 'valid` to chr(13)`';`

Comment: Not understand which chr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198652/discussion-between-andrea-manzi-and-abdul-awal).

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead,

```
$this->assertStringContainsString('valid',$output);
```